# Transforming coordinates of feature in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-3, projection

I want to transform the coordinates for an entire feature in openlayers.  I have had success using ol.proj.transform to transform a single coordinate to a different projection, but is there any function that you can feed an entire feature, and all the coordinates within that feature will be transformed to the desired projection?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need `ol.geom.Geometry.transform`

If you have your feature, then you can do:

```
src = 'EPSG:3857'
dest = 'EPSG:4326'
feature.getGeometry().transform(src, dest)
```

The docs are here:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html#transform

If you do not want the geometry modified in place, first `clone()` it and then use this function on the clone.

Comment: Thanks!  That is the solution.

Comment: Great, glad that worked for you. Could you mark the answer as 'accepted'? This help other users know that the question is solved, which makes it more useful.